# How to swipe right to show new View Controller in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I want to be able to swipe right in my `ViewController` which will show another view controller, `CommunitiesViewController`.

I have looked on other threads and found some ways of doing this though I believe they are for Swift 2.

This is the code I am using in my `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("respondToSwipeGesture")))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
}

  func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    print ("Swiped right")

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:


            //change view controllers

            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

            let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommunitiesID") as! CommunitiesViewController

            self.present(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)    


        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I have given `CommunitiesViewController` a storyboard ID of `CommunitiesID`.

But this does not work and the app crashes when I swipe right with the following error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrong selector format, change to:

```
action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture)
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
```

or

```
action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture(_:))
func respondToSwipeGesture(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Gesture Recognizer     
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

}
```

then add the function:

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
            //right view controller
            let newViewController = firstViewController() 
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            //left view controller
            let newViewController = secondViewController() 
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job, but  I have problem when in controller insert Table View or Scroll View , swipe no work perfect :(